# Is there a way to reshape/convert a inhomogeneous numpy array of weird size to a square-shaped array?

Tags: pytorch, numpy-ndarray, openai-gym

I've been trying to train a policy gradient agent to perform on LunarLander environment by OpenAI gym.
the observation array after calling the env.reset() function comes out to be a weird shaped array which cant be converted to a boxed tensor using the pytorch framework.
Constantly trying to solve the bug using several methods.
ps. reshaping not working
code snippet below from both the files

```py
for i in range(num_episodes):
        print('episodes', i, 'score', score)
        done = False
        score = 0
        observation = env.reset()
        while not done:
            print(observation)
            action = agent.choose_action(observation)
```

now the choose_action() is defines as follows:

```py
def forward(self, observation):
        state = T.tensor(np.array(observation)).to(self.device)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

def choose_action(self, observation):
        probabilities = F.softmax(self.policy.forward(observation))
        print(probabilities, probabilities.size())
```

running this code throwing the following error:

```py
(array([-0.00508328,  1.4105566 , -0.514903  , -0.01617732,  0.00589709,
        0.11663332,  0.        ,  0.        ], dtype=float32), {})
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Reinforcement\rl_codes\Policy Gradients\main_torch.py", line 29, in <module>
    observation = np.pad(observation, (0, padding), mode='constant')
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in pad
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py", line 737, in pad
    array = np.asarray(array)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I've tried making the inhomogeneous array with the weird shape to a array with box shape and pad with missing entries with zeros using the np.ceil and np.pad() method in the code below but got no luck.

```py
n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(len(observation))))
print(n)
padding = n**2 - len(observation)
observation = np.pad(observation, (0, padding), mode='constant')
```

Comment: What is the shape of `observation`, and what is the size of your `fc` layers? From what you provide, I believe it is just a shape mismatch issue, so providing more information would be very helpful